# How to use a variable inside an awk statement?

Tags: awk, scripting

I have a script like this

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "Enter the matching pattern"
read pattern
path= /home/siva/
echo "Navigating to $path"
cd $path
cat filename|awk '/$pattern/ {for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {getline;print}}'
```

i am not able to get the entered `$pattern` when i execute the script.

Comment: Try to format your question.

Comment: You mean something like `awk -v pattern=$pattern '/$pattern/ {for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {getline;print}}'` ? please try to edit your code so it's readable

Comment: @Dani_l no, this would look for a literal `$pattern`. Instead, you have to say `$0 ~ pattern`. In general, you cannot use variables within `/ /` because awk does not have a way to distinguish them from literal text.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo | awk -v variable='This is variable!' 'END{print variable}'
```

You pass variables with `-v` keyword. And don't use **$** for variable - it is not a bash. Awk uses **$** to access a field.

Comment: I saw your answer after already posting my comment

Comment: Note that some `awk` implementations need the `variabl=...` to be a separate argument from `-v`, so `awk -v variable=...` is more portable than `awk -vvariable=...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "Enter the matching pattern"
IFS= read -r pattern
path=/home/siva/
echo "Navigating to $path"
cd "$path" || exit
awk -v pattern="$pattern" '$0 ~ pattern{for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {getline;print}}' filename
```

1. Use awk -v to pass variables into the awk script
2. cat is unnecessary - awk can handle files directly

Comment: awk -v pattern=$pattern '/$0 ~ pattern/ {for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {getline;print}}' filename'   - This doesn't work,

Comment: Try without the slashes, as per my last edit

Comment: Dani... Perfect. That worked!!

Comment: What should i do to get the matching pattern also displayed in results?

Comment: Using `-v` mangles backslash characters, using environment variables and `ENVIRON["the_variable"]` in `awk` is a better approach considering that regular expressions often contain backslash characters

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas -v example: `a=aaa;echo | awk -va=$a '{print a}'` However I can't seem to get it to work with ENVIRON["a"] - neither `a=aaa;echo | awk 'BEGIN{a=ENVIRON["a"]} {print a}'` nor `a=aaa;echo | awk '{print ENVIRON["a"]}'` works

Comment: `a=aaa` defines a shell variable. You need to export it if you want it passed as an environment variable to `awk`, or use `a=aaaa awk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["a"]}'`. See the dup question for details.